# which is best between two loops?

Tags: c

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<=5;++i)
{ printf("my name");
}
```

or

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{  printf("my name");
}
```

Explain me the working of both loops how they will work and difference between them and which one is best?

Comment: In a nutshell, there is no difference.

Comment: Read a good C programming book. Maybe the second loop is meant to be `for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)`

Comment: The second loop won't compile as you have not declared `i`.

Comment: @RPGillespie are you sure about that?

Comment: @SouravGhosh at the time of posting, `i` was not declared. As it stands the second loop *still* won't compile under most `C` compilers (unless you are using C99 mode) because `i` is declared inside the `for` conditional.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the second loop is

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++) {  printf("my name\n"); };
```

The difference between the first one is the scope of `i`. For the loop above it is only the body of the `for` loop.

So if you add after both loops something like

```
printf("finally i=%d\n", i);
```

it won't compile in the second case (since `i` won't even be defined inside that last `printf`).

Read wikipage on [scopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) of variables.

BTW: as a beginner: always end the format strings in `printf` with a `\n` (or learn about `fflush`). and always compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "better" or "worse" here, because the code fragments differ in a significant way:

- In the first fragment, variable `i` remains in scope after the loop, while
- In the second loop, the variable goes out of scope.

When you need to use the value of `i` after the loop, use the first construct; otherwise, use the second construct.

One common case when you need to use `i` after the loop is when the loop could end before reaching a stopping condition from the loop header, for example, because you have a conditional `break` in the middle of the loop. In general, however, you should prefer the second form, which keeps the scope of the loop variable to the loop itself.